# Python xrange countdown make

Tags: python, python-2.7, range, xrange

For the following code:

```
for slot in xrange(360-1,-1,-1):
```

What does it output ?

How do I obtain my desired output of:

```
360-359-358-357-356....-- 3-2-1
```

Comment: The range will include the first number and *not* include the second.  So you want `xrange(360, 0, -1)`.

Comment: The desired string will have 1329 characters. Are you sure you want to print that as one line? Unless you just mean you want to count from 360 to 1, and not the literal string `'360-359-358...'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
>>> for slot in xrange(360, 0, -1):
...     print(slot)
```

- The first entry is where you are starting from.
- The second entry is where you want to stop.
- The third entry is your step. In this case -1 indicates, "go down by 1 each time"

If you are looking to output your list with hyphen's in between, then you can do something like this:

```
'-'.join([str(i) for i in xrange(360, 0, -1)])
```

To break it down from the inside:

- `[i for i in xrange(360, 0, -1)]` : A list comprehension that will perform your range operation and create a list of the specified range.
- `join` : Convert the list to a string
- `-` : Indicates to separate each "part" with a hyphen

Comment: I just looked at your output. Are you looking for exactly: 360-359-358? all on one line in exactly that format?

Comment: @Ademd you need to redefine your question then because idjaw's answer is correct.

Comment: yeah either that or you REALLY want those '-'s so do this: `'-'.join([str(_) for _ in xrange(360, 0, -1)])`

Comment: It does not turn on when there is no space

Comment: @Ademd I am at a loss to understand what behaviour you are expecting. Could you please review your original post and be more specific as to what it is you are trying to output. Based on the information you provided, my solution works.